# Add border under column headers in QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, border, qtablewidget

I have a table widget with two column header in a dialog that looks like this:

[image]

There is a separation between the column headers named "Index" and "Label", but there is no separating border between these header and the row below them. How can this be added?

Say the table is instantiated as:

```
table = QTableWidget(6, 2, self)
```

I know that I can get the first horizontal header as a QTableWidgetItem by doing `headerItem = table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)` modify some properties and set it back, but I'm unsure of what properties to set or if there is a more straightforward approach.

## EDIT:

If I extract the header and set the style, shadow, and line width properties of its underlying frame via:

```
header = table.horizontalHeader()
header.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box | QFrame.Plain)
header.setLineWidth(1)
table.setHorizontalHeader(header)
```

I end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

This way a border does show up around the header. This could be done for each header item separately, but there are a couple of concerns:

1. The border extends past the width of the cells below
2. I'd still have to match the color of the frame to the existing lines for this to look somewhat decent.
3. It appears that the vertical line that separates "Index" and "Label" is shifted in relation to the line separating the cells below (unless my eyes are playing tricks on me).

Is there a more 'built in' way to do this?

Comment: `QTableWidget::horizontalHeader()` returns a pointer to the associated `QHeaderItem` which (a few levels down) inherits `QFrame`.  Does setting the frame style/shape/width have any effect?

Comment: What you've suggested creates a border around the entire header, and could be used for each header item individually, but there are some issues. See edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. The first thing to note is that this only happens on Windows 10. On other OS, there is nothing to repair, it just works. On Windows 10 however, the painting primitives are not painting the bottom border (which is the default Windows 10 table header style - as can be seen in windows file explorer). This is unfortunate but can be solved with the following style sheet:

```
if(QSysInfo::windowsVersion()==QSysInfo::WV_WINDOWS10){
    setStyleSheet(
        "QHeaderView::section{"
            "border-top:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-left:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-right:1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "background-color:white;"
            "padding:4px;"
        "}"
        "QTableCornerButton::section{"
            "border-top:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-left:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-right:1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "background-color:white;"
        "}");}
```

Sorry to bother you with C++ code but It should be easy enough to translate into valid pyqt code.

Note1: The background-color and padding are unfortunate but they are necessary to make our custom rendering looks like the default one.

Note2: The color of the border is the color of the grid on my system. I did not use the color of the default header.

Note3: The `QTableCornerButton::section` part is necessary to add the missing border below the top left corner. If the vertical header is not visible, the missing line is invisible too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, the equivalent in PyQt6 would be: `if QSysInfo.productType() == "windows" and QSysInfo.productVersion() == "10"`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
header.setStyleSheet( "QHeaderView::section { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }" );
```

Comment: I tried this first but unfortunately on Windows 10 it's not enough.

Comment: Odd, it's working on Windows 10 for me. What's your result?

Comment: The result is that I don't get the border under the header. In your code the header is `table.horizontalHeader()` right ?

Comment: Yep. Do you have any other stylesheet running that might interfere with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QHeaderView::section {
border: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

A slight adjustment to your code worked for me:

```
 horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet( "QHeaderView::section { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }" )
```

Comment: copy of "i know nothing"'s answer

Comment: This flag is incorrect, the answers are different, please compare the first words in the code. My code works, while "i know nothing"'s does not.